# Pass a .sql file to SQL Server for execution

Tags: c#, sql-server, database

I have an application that generates sql insert AND update statements in an offline/disconnected manner such that each query that I would normally run is simply written to a txt file. I do this so that the application can continue to run from any server without latency and will continue to work even if the database were to become unavailable.

At some point, I'd like my c# app to pass this file of queries to SQL Server to be executed so all the pending inserts and updates can be performed. Ideally the list of updates/inserts would happen in a transaction so I can see that it finished and delete the local txt file so I don't attempt to run it again.

What's the best way to accomplish this? FTP the file to the server and then what? Or should I just open a connection to the db and run the entire thing as one giant query (CommandText)? My concern is that the file could be 10, 20 or 50 megabytes so I'm looking for something more robust than passing t-sql over a SqlCommand. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

My suggestion would be to create a central clearinghouse for these files.  For example, create a WCF service that you can upload .sql files to the server.  Then have the WCF service process the .sql file and delete it.  This way you could continue to be disconnected and your applications wouldn't need to know how to handle the files except that they get uploaded.  Basically a fire-and-forget method of handling the files.

Answer (score 1):

If this file oriented method actually works for you, then all you need is to use the `ExecuteNonQuery` method of the `SqlCommand` class. Load each file into a string, separate the string on the batch separators (`GO`), then create a `SqlCommand` for each batch, setting the `CommandText` property to the batch of SQL. When you call `ExecuteNonQuery`, the batch will be sent to the server and executed. Errors will be returned as exceptions, and messages can be returned to you as well.

However, although this may work in your case, it won't work in the general case. In general, you may have several disconnected users attempting to make changes to the same data. To make this work, you'll need a more general synchronization technique.